# What is the difference between *p and *&p

Tags: c, pointers, printf, operators

I'm having problem with this code,

```
int main()
{
 char *p = "example";
 printf("%s\n", *&p);   This is giving desired output
 printf("%s\n", *p);    Here giving segmentation fault
 return 0;
}
```

My question is what is the difference between *&p and *p here and how they are working in this code?

Comment: `%s` expects a pointer to a string. `*p` is a single char and hence the segfault. `&p` is a pointer to a pointer and after dereferencing with the `*` operator you get back the original pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*&p` in fact is the same as `p` and has type char *.

So these calls

```
printf("%s\n", *&p);
printf("%s\n", p);
```

produce the same result.

`*p` has type `char` and may not be used with the format specifier `%s`. Otherwise using it with the format specifier `%s` results in undefined behavior

You could write instead

```
printf("%c\n", *p);
        ^^
```

Pay attention to that it is not always `*&p` is equivalent to `p`.

For example you may not apply the operator & to a `non-lvalue`.

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * f( void )
{
    char *p = "Hello";

    return p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%s\n", f() );
    // The statement below will not compile if to uncomment it
    // printf( "%s\n", *&f() );

    return 0;
}
```

In this program the returned temporary object from the function `f` is not lvalue.

Comment: I would put a code block around `char *` to make it a little more readable but seems good otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`&p` is the address of the variable `p`, with a type `char **`. The value `*&p` is then dereferencing this address, giving an l-value of type `char *` for the variable `p`. `*&p` is exactly equivalent to `p`.

`*p` is dereferencing the variable `p`. This gives an l-value of type `char` to the character pointed to by `p`, in this case the `'e'` at the beginning of the string. (Note that although it is of type `char`, this value is read-only because `p` is a pointer to a string literal.)

Due to default type conversions, you end up passing an `int` of value `'e'` to `printf`. `printf` treats this value as an address, because you use the format specifier `"%s"`, `printf` dereferences this pointer, which is an invalid memory access..

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
1)   p   is a char pointer storing the address where is stored first 'e' letter in "example"
2)   *p  is the value stored at that address stored in p, that means the value 'e' 
3)   *&p = *(&p) is the value pointed by the address of p then *&p == p
```

then given 1,2,3 :

```
printf("%s\n", *&p);  // is equivalent to printf("%s\n",p)      which is OK
printf("%s\n", *p);   // is equivalent to printf("%s\n",'e')    which is wrong 
                      // because 'e' is interpreted as an address
```